# Why Vue global EventBus do not work in my project

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I am using vue js in laravel, I need to use the global event bus. I created event-bus.js, and I import it to where I need to use it; when I click, events are generated, but there are no reactions from the listener. I tried everything, but it doesn’t work. Please help me, I have been working for 3 days

I tried to create an eventBus in app.js, but it didn't help either

My EditDiscountComponent

```
import { EventBus } from "../../../event-bus";

editDiscount () {
        const data = {
          discount_id: this.discountData.discount_id,
          status: this.discountData.status,
          type: this.discountData.type,
          percentage:this.discountData.percentage,
          amount:this.discountData.amount,
        };

        EventBus.$emit('update-discount', data);

         this.languages.forEach(lang => {
              if (lang.code && this.discountData[lang.code] !== undefined) {
                  data[lang.code] = this.discountData[lang.code];
              }
          });
        this.$store.dispatch(actions.EDIT_DISCOUNT, data)
          .then(res => {
            if (res && res.data.status) {

              // window.location.href = '/admin/discounts';

            } else {
              this.$store.commit(mutations.SET_SNACKBAR_SHOW, true);
              this.$store.commit(mutations.SET_SNACKBAR_TEXT, res.data.message);
            }
          }).catch(console.error);

      },
    },
```

My ProductCOmponent

```
import { EventBus } from "../../../event-bus";

 mounted() {
            EventBus.$on('update-discount', ($data) => {
                console.log($data);
            });
            this.getCategories();
            this.getProducts();
        },
```

I tried the callback of the function using a different method, but no results, and I tried this listener in the mount (), and this did not help

Comment: Try importing it as import EventBus from '@/eventBus'

Comment: What does this '@/eventBus'?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your `eventBus.js` file inside `src` folder of your project which will look something like this

```
import Vue from 'vue'
export default new Vue()
```

And try to import it as shown below:

```
import EventBus from '@/eventBus'
```

Or this might help you https://alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus/

Comment: I have event-bus.js, and I import it, that code is in it

Comment: My event-bus.js

import Vue from 'vue';
export const EventBus = new Vue();

Comment: Can u try will above one.

Comment: If you mean to try several implementations, then in my code I used a lot, but it doesn’t work